# upload image with Chopper

Tags: android, flutter, image-uploading

How to upload an image to the server with **chopper library**? I tried the search on google but, I couldn't manage to get one.

What I have tried is

**Function handle creating the chopper client**

```
static ApiService create(String accessToken) {
final client = ChopperClient(
    baseUrl: 'http://192.168.43.125:8000/api',
    services: [
      _$ApiService(),
    ],
    converter: JsonConverter(),
    interceptors: [
      HeadersInterceptor({
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      }),
      HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    ]);
return _$ApiService(client);}
```

**API**

```
@Post(path: '/inspectionStore',)
@multipart
Future<Response> storeInspection(
@Part("field") String field, @PartFile("file") http.MultipartFile file);
```

**Code that do the work**

```
File actualFile = photoSection.postImage[0];
http.MultipartFile file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', actualFile.path,contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg'));

var response = await Provider.of<ApiService>(context).storeInspection('some name',file);
```

**This is what the server retrieve (Laravel Log file)**
[image]

How can I get a proper data that can be used?

Comment: Hey, did you get any solution? I'm facing error while uploading image to server.  `RequestInterceptor` might be looking for `Body` in `request`. But I only have a `MultiPart` request with only one parameter `file`.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little late but this could save someone. So, you need to provide the path to your image as string

```
@multipart
Future<Response> storeInspection(
@Part("field") String field, @PartFile("file") String file);
```

then

```
File actualFile = photoSection.postImage[0];

var response = await Provider.of<ApiService>(context).storeInspection('some name',file.path);
```